# Is there an elegant way to deal with log-transformed axes and units from the units package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, units-of-measurement

The units package is very useful for dealing with units. However, it's not clear for me how to plot variables with units on log-transformed axes. In base plot, adding `log="y"` parameter results in an error. The same goes for ggplot2 using the standard `scale_y_log10()` function. Alternatively, using the ggforce function `scale_y_unit(trans="log10")` works, but produces a cryptic axis label. 
 - Is there a way to make this work in base plot? 
 - Is there a way to keep `scale_y_unit(trans="log10")` from messing with the axis label and instead focus on the numbers on the axes and the data?

```
library(units)

# Take cars data frame: stopping dist (ft) vs speed (mph)
plot(cars)

# Using base plot
Distance = set_units(cars$dist, ft)
Speed = set_units(cars$speed, mph)
plot(x=Speed, y=Distance, log="y") 
# Error in Ops.units(y, 0) : 
#  both operands of the expression should be "units" objects

# Using ggplot
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
df = cars
df$Disance = set_units(df$dist, ft)
df$Speed = set_units(df$speed, mph)

qplot(x=Speed, y=Distance, data=df) +
  scale_y_unit(trans="log10")
# Y-axis is cryptically labelled with "Distance (lg(re 0.3048 m))"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of applying the log transformation inside scale you can apply it via `coord_trans`. (BTW: adds tick labels to the plot) Try this:

```r
library(units)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
df = cars
df$Distance = set_units(df$dist, ft)
df$Speed = set_units(df$speed, mph)

qplot(x=Speed, y=Distance, data=df) +
  scale_y_unit() +
  coord_trans(y = "log10")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>